# Ошибка: ArgumentException: TargetType для ControlTemplate "ScrollBar" не соответствует типу "ListBox" на основе шаблона

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, list

Пишет, что не возможно использовать `Command` в `ListBox`. Строка пишет, как ошибка `Command="Scroll.LineUpCommand`и в последующих `Command` во всем коде. Ошибка такова: ArgumentException: TargetType для ControlTemplate "ScrollBar" не соответствует типу "ListBox" на основе шаблона. Где я допустил ошибку?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Height="18"
            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButtonStyle}"
            Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand">
                <Path Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
               Data="M 0 4L 8 4 L 4 0 Z"/>
            </RepeatButton>
            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1"
             IsDirectionReversed="True" ViewportSize="0">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                    Style="{StaticResource SrcollBarPageButtonStyle}"/>
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbStyle}"/> 
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButtonStyle}"/>
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton 
                Grid.Row="3" Height="18"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButtonStyle}"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineDownComand"
                Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Row="3" Height="18"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButtonStyle}"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand">
                <Path Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                      Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
            </RepeatButton>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1 0 1 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource StandardBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource StandardBorderBrush}"
                             Fill="{StaticResource StandardBrush}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style> 
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}"> 
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Grid Margin="1">
                        <Ellipse Name="Border" StrokeThickness="1"
                                Stroke="{StaticResource StandardBorderBrush}"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource StandardBrush}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Fill"
                                    Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style> 
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatBehavior}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Правильно ли я добавил шаблон в `ListBox`?

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          Template="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}">
            <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Ну, вы пытаетесь `ListBox`'у дать темплейт, который подходит только для скроллбара (`TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}"`). Неудивительно, что системе это не нравится.

Comment: Тогда как это возможно сделать конкретно для `ListBox`  c использованием `ScrollViewer` ? Ещё подчёркивает `Command` и пишет:  Недопустимое значение для свойства "Command": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue"

Comment: Вы не можете никак заставить `ListBox` принять темплейт, не предназначенный для него. Объясните, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: Тогда как это сделать ? Мне нужно чтобы дизайн `ScrollBar` работал в `ListBox` там где я хочу его указать. У меня там находиться рабочий плейлист и нужно изменить для него скролбар. Есть код похожий на этот, но с изменением. Остается несколько таких ошибок Недопустимое значение для свойства "Command":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue" , эти ошибки остаются, но код  работает . Ссылка на код: http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/Template/level17/17_12.php как мне применить  код, так чтобы не было этих ошибок ?

Comment: Вам нужно изменить скроллбар **внутри** `ListBox`'а? Ну так это совсем другое дело. Что ж вы пропихиваете скроллбар самому листбоксу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно подменить скроллбар внутри листбокса, используйте стиль.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Did not work!</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>  
</Grid>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз это и помогло к тому коду, что по ссылке, но `Command` всё ещё ругается на указанные значения которые были написаны в коде.

Comment: @Glayder: А на какую конкретно строчку ругается?

Comment: Это последний стиль который ругается и не позволяет задействовать остальные ресурсы. `<Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">` Ошибка: TargetType для ControlTemplate должен представлять Control, Page, PageFunctionBase или подкласс того же класса. Тип "RepeatBehavior" является недопустимым.

Comment: @Glayder: `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatBehavior}">` — вы тут с типом не ошиблись?

Comment: Скажу так, мне нужно сделать другой скролбар, а от этого я уже отталкиваюсь. Код был взять с книжки Metthew MacDonald "Pro WPF in C# 2010: WIndows Presentation Foundation.NET4" стр.500. В коде, я уверен, ошибиться там не могли.

Comment: @Glayder: А вы всё же прочитайте код внимательно. Вы создаёте стиль для `RepeatButton`, а темплейт почему-то для `RepeatBehavior`. Вы думаете, в книгах не бывает ошибок?

Comment: Да, это при автозаполнение получился `RepeatBehavior`.